# ¿Cómo realizar una query en un rango con un vector como clave?

Tags: api, nosql, couchdb

Estoy intentando filtrar un rango específico de registros desde `CouchDB`. La clave (*key*) de la vista es una array con 3 valores numéricos y un string:

```
[Num1,Num2,Num3,String1]
```

Lo que estoy buscando son los registros cuyo `Num2` sea mayor a `A1` y cuyo `Num3` sea menor a `A2`.

La query la estoy haciendo usando `startkey` y `endkey`:

```
startkey=[Num1,A1,0,String1]
endkey=[Num1,100000,A2,String1]
```

El problema es que los registros que retorna la vista tienen valores Num2 están entren `A1` y `A2`. Pero los valores de `Num3` son mayores a `Num2` y no debe ser así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La query estaba mal diseñada, en el caso de los arrays CouchDB los ordena de acuerdo a su contenido, por ende a al poner en el endkey el limite de Num2 como 100000 estaba permitiendo que otros registros ingresaran en el resultado. La solución fue definir un limite real tangible para Num2.

Ejemplo:

```
[1,1,0,""]
[1,1,1,""]
[1,2,1,""]
[1,3,2,""]
[1,4,2,""]
[1,5,2,""]
[1,6,3,""]
[1,7,4,""]
[1,8,5,""]
[1,100000,7,""]
```

Por ejemplo, si A1 es "2" y A2 es "3", al poner en el endkey el valor de Num2 como 100000 estoy permitiendo que:

```
[1,7,4,""]
[1,8,5,""]
```

ingresen en la vista. Para solucionar el problema debo poner Num2 en el endkey en un valor tangible por ejemplo "6". De esta forma los registros seleccionados son los correctos.

```
[1,1,0,""]
[1,1,1,""]
[1,2,1,""]
[1,3,2,""]
[1,4,2,""]
[1,5,2,""]
[1,6,3,""]
```

PD: en mi caso como Num3 siempre es mayor que Num2, la starkey y endkey quedaron de la siguiente forma:

```
startkey=[Num1,A1,A1,String1]
endkey=[Num1,A2,A2,String1]
```